# Open CSV with Office365 Excel through Script

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, csv, office365

**Goal**

Open a CSV file with Office365's Excel without saving the file on the client machine

**Problem**

Saving the raw data on the client machine will lead to a lot of old excel files laying around and I would like to prevent this. In a perfect world, I would like to have a button in my application that says "Export to Excel" which opens office365's excel application with the data. Just as you would do with a local installation. After migrating to the cloud, saving files locally, this feels like a step in the wrong direction.

Is it possible to send data to an excel sheet with scripting?

**Background**

This is an internal application that will not be accessible online and my users are using Google Chrome.

**Manual Solution (Not accepted)**

1. Save the file on the machine
2. Open Excel
3. Use the import tool

**Possible Solution if nothing else (over engineering)**

1. Backend sets up a network drive
2. Saves the CSV to the drive
3. User opens Excel and imports the file from his/her space on the shared drive

This feels wrong. Is it possible to open a tab with excel, use some kind of local storage space, window events, broadcasting channel or query arguments to insert data? Query is probably the worst possible option as I dont know the size of the data. I can't seem to find the right documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the csv raw data into a SQL database and then have a single html page that connects to the DB and displays the plain text on a blank html page. Maybe add a security token using a GET request and then all you would have to do is open the url from within excel instead of a file on the local computer.